# How to get the detection time in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

This is a face distance measurement program with OpenCV. It shows "Too close" if the user is less than 50cm from the screen and "Too Far" if the user is more than 100cm distance. I need to make it to display the result (Too close/Too far) if the detection time is more than 10 seconds.

Ex: If the user stays too close (<50cm) to the screen for more than 10s, then it will show result as too close.

I have provided the code to this program below

```
import cvzone
from cvzone.FaceMeshModule import FaceMeshDetector
from plyer import notification

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
detector = FaceMeshDetector(maxFaces=1)  # No of faces to be detected.

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    img, faces = detector.findFaceMesh(img, draw=False)

    if faces:
        face = faces[0]
        pointLeft = face[145]
        pointRight = face[374]

        # for drawing
        # cv2.line(img, pointLeft, pointRight, (0, 200, 0), 3)
        # cv2.circle(img, pointLeft, 5, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
        # cv2.circle(img, pointRight, 5, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)

        w, _ = detector.findDistance(pointLeft, pointRight)  # width in pixels shown from the camera
        W = 6.3  # distance between eyes average of female and male
        # male average is about 6.4
        # female average is about 6.2

        # finding the focal length
        # d = 50  # distance from the cam
        # f = (w*d)/W   # focal point
        # print(f)

        # finding distance between
        f = 642
        d = (W * f) / w
        print(d)

        # cvzone.putTextRect(img, f'Distance: {int(d)}cm',
        #                    (face[10][0]-100, face[10][1] - 50),
        #                    scale=2)

        if d < 50:
            cvzone.putTextRect(img, f'Too Close',
                               (face[10][0] - 100, face[10][1] - 50),
                               scale=2)
            # notification.notify(
            #     title='Face Distance',
            #     message='Too Close!',
            #     app_icon=None,
            #     timeout=2,
            # )

        elif d > 100:
            cvzone.putTextRect(img, f'Too Far',
                               (face[10][0] - 100, face[10][1] - 50),
                               scale=2)

            # notification.notify(
            #     title='Face Distance',
            #     message='Too Far!',
            #     app_icon=None,
            #     timeout=2,
            # )

        else:
            cvzone.putTextRect(img, f'Distance: {int(d)}cm',
                               (face[10][0] - 100, face[10][1] - 50),
                               scale=2)

    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: Maybe remove commented code as they're not helpful

Answer (score 1):

Stop me if I'm wrong but I have the impression that you don't take into account the points **3D axes**, you only take into account the distance between the leftmost point and the rightmost point.

If the user has a slight head rotation, this will corrupt your calculation since it only takes into account the distance from those two points **screen coordinates** (two axes).

By taking into account all axis, you could calculate the middle of these same two points and send your messages only if the "depth" axis *(generally [z])* value of your middle point is too small/big.

Actually working on how getting the 'z' value of them, I'll let you know if you're interested (and if I find the way to get them ofc). Good luck!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).